# IntelliJ formatting methods incorrectly

Tags: intellij-idea, formatting

How can I set my IntelliJ formatter to work better. What I mean is that I have the following code(for example):

```
 request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEBNF/jsp/view/some.jsp").forward
                (request, response);
```

formatted as you see it. But isn't it more correctly to be formatted like this:

```
 request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEBNF/jsp/view/some.jsp")
                                                    .forward(request, response);
```

The first way is awful in my opinion. So Is there a way to create it like the second example.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the formatting manually and prevent IDEA from joining the lines. Go to **Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Java**, select the **Wrapping and Braces** tab on the right side and check the option **Line breaks** in the section **Keep when reformatting**.

Comment: This is checked, but the formatting is bad. 
Thanks for your attention.